# Scrolling Disable over a Youtube Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I am working on my personal website.
My website contains a youtube iframe. When mousing over it, the document stop scrolling. I want the main document to continue scrolling even if the mouse was over the youtube video.

```
<div class="video-container"><iframe width="950" height="480" style="margin-top: 10px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fL3QKagSn1s#t=0m00s" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen/></iframe></div>
            </div>
```

[enter link description here](http://tonykadis.com/tonyk/index.html)

Comment: There is same problem and solved [Vimeo iFrame Stealing Mouse Wheel Event on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418920/vimeo-iframe-stealing-mouse-wheel-event-on-firefox)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vimeo iFrame Stealing Mouse Wheel Event on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418920/vimeo-iframe-stealing-mouse-wheel-event-on-firefox)

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping it into a div and set that div's z-index:10 or something, so this will cause to not mouseover to the iframe but to the div.

Comment: I checked your page and this wont be working. What you have to do is, fire a JS function when mouseover the iframe and calculate how much scrolled down or up and dynamiclly sum it with the current above height of your page.